# PHP+Ldap+SSO+Windows any complete example

Tags: php, ldap, single-sign-on

I have a website http://example.com which accepts username and password and log in user with permission.

Now I do not have any username and password table inside my website.
When user put username and password , it goes to a ldap server checks if user already exists and log them in depending on permission set.

Now problem is I need to skip the part where user need to put username and password into website.

I want whenever user log in to their PC (mainly windows. If possible then mac and linux also), there PC username and password can be supplied to browser , so they do not need to enter Username and Password once more.

I already tried following
1.)mod_auth_sspi  but it has compatibility issue with Apache 2.4
2.)krb5 which have compatibility issue with PHP 7

Do anyone have any working solution Which can work with PHP,LDAP + SSO.

Below is a code block which does ldap authentication.

```
//using ldap bind anonymously
$host = "ldap.forumsys.com";
$port = 389;
$base_dn = "ou=users,o=forumsys";

// connect to ldap server
$ldapConn = ldap_connect($host,$port)
or die("Could not connect to LDAP server.");
ldap_set_option($ldapConn, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
ldap_set_option($ldapConn, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);
if ($ldapConn) {

    // binding anonymously
    $ldapbind = ldap_bind($ldapConn,$base_dn);



    if ($ldapbind) {
        echo "LDAP bind anonymous successful...<br>";

        //Let's search User
        $uname = "myuname";  **//THIS SHOULD BE FETCHED AUTOMATICALLY**
$password = "password"; **// SOME MECHANISM TO GET ANY KIND OF HASH INSTEAD**
        echo "Let's search User : $uname <br>";
        $result = ldap_search($ldapConn, $base_dn, "(cn=$uname)");
        $entries = ldap_get_entries($ldapConn, $result);
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($entries);

        if ($entries['count'] > 0) {
            if (ldap_bind($ldapConn, $entries[0]['dn'], $password)) {
                // user with mail $mail is checked with password $password
                echo '<br>user auth success';
            }else{
                echo '<br>user auth failed';
            }
        }

    } else {
        echo "LDAP bind anonymous failed...";
    }





}
```